# Alternate column order using ngFor

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ngfor

How can I alternate the order of the columns for each row using ngFor?

For example here the image will always be on the right. How can I do so that in each row I alternate and the image shows one on the left and one on the right and so on?

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let servicio of servicios">
  <div class="col-lg-5">
    {{ servicio.titulo }}
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <img src="{{ servicio.imagen }}" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [local variables available](https://alligator.io/angular/ngfor-directive/#available-local-variables), for example `even` and `odd`, in `*ngFor` to alternate the order of the columns with two `ngIf` directives. One of them makes `titulo` the first column for rows with an even index, the other one makes it the last column for rows with an odd index.

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let servicio of servicios; let even=even">
  <div *ngIf="even" class="col-lg-5">
    {{ servicio.titulo }}
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <img src="{{ servicio.imagen }}" alt="">
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="!even" class="col-lg-5">
    {{ servicio.titulo }}
  </div>
</div>
```

See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-example-9ebt3t) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a pro with css, but I think what you want can be achieved using `ngClass`

You would need to make these changes.

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let servicio of servicios; let i = index">
  <div class="col-lg-5" [ngClass]="{'align-left': i % 2 == 0, 'align-right': i%2 != 0}">
  {{ servicio.titulo }}
</div>
<div class="col-lg-7">
  <img src="{{ servicio.imagen }}" alt=""
       [ngClass]="{'align-left': i % 2 != 0, 'align-right': i%2 == 0}">
</div>
```

Notice that they are "switched", the title shows on left when `i % 2 == 0` and the image aligns to the right.

Comment: Please note that you can take advantage of the `even` and `odd` variables to make the syntax more readable (without using `i % 2 == 0`). You can see my answer for an example of how to use `even`.

Comment: Didn't know you could do that, great answer! @ConnorsFan